# How to get available ADFS server(s) and realm(s) from SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, adfs

From a browser, if I have a single ADFS (STS), when I attempt to access a SharePoint site, I can get the ADFS URL and realm from the redirect in HTTP reponse for authentication.  If I have more than 1 STS servers configured on a SharePoint site, I will be prompted (Home Realm Discovery) with available realms and ADFS servers to select where to authenticate.

But is there a way to get these programmatically from SharePoint (not thru HTTP redirect or web page prompting), e.g. SOAP API or REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ADFS direct API.

There are [AD FS 2.0 Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee892329.aspx).

The one you want is "Get-ADFSClaimsProviderTrust".

You can access PowerShell from e.g. C#. Then you would just have to parse out the response.

Comment: You could have the PowerShell code in a web service which you can call.